# Is this Nash-Equilibrium valid?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

The game is as follows:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
&A&B\\
\hline
A&2;3&2;3\\
\hline
B&-1;2&1;2\\
\hline
C&-1;3&4;2\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

I've written a program that calculates nash equilibria. Here is one that it calculated with the corresponding payoff vectors:

[image]

The greyed-out strategies are the mixed strategies.
Is this equilibrium indeed valid? To me it seems to be valid, but I am not sure as other tools, such as Gambit, did not calculate this equilibrium. So is there something wrong with the algorithm I programmed or not?

Comment: Could you say a little bit more about the snapshot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct, but maybe the tools didn't calculate this particular one because it lies at the intersection of two families of Nash equilibria.  The first family has

$$
P_1(B) = \begin{cases}
    0 & p < 2/5 \\
    q & p = 2/5 \\
    1 & p > 2/5
\end{cases}
$$
$$
P_1(A, F) = \begin{cases}
    1 & p < 2/5 \\
    1-q & p = 2/5 \\
    0 & p > 2/5
\end{cases}
$$
$$
P_2(C) = p
$$
$$
P_2(D) = 1-p
$$

and the other family has

$$
P_1(B) = r
$$
$$
P_1(A, F) = 1-r
$$
$$
P_2(C) = 2/5
$$
$$
P_2(D) = 3/5
$$

where $p, q, r$ are arbitrary in $[0, 1]$.